# Tensorflow extreme slow down after update

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I have recently ran:

- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade

on Ubuntu 18.04. I noticed that it upgraded some nvidia related packages.
After the upgrade tensorflow has slowed down extremely. Before the upgrade training a test network took 75 seconds and now that takes about 15 minutes.

My versions:

- cuda 10.0
- nvidia driver 415.27
- Cuda compilation tools release 9.1, V9.1.85

In tensorflow conda env:

- cudatoolkit 9.2
- cudnn 7.2.1
- python 3.6.8
- tensorflow/tensorflow-base/tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0

I have tried many things to fix this including new conda environment just for tensorflow, other gpu drivers (390, 410), re-installing gpu drivers.

I don't know how to find the root of the problem. I am using a gtx 1080ti. Is there some kind of benchmark I can run?

I tried to run the [tensorflow cnn benchmark](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks) but that requires tf_nightly_gpu which doesn't support cuda 10.0 yet.

Comment: Sounds like TensorFlow may not be using your GPU anymore. Try `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib` and then see what `device_lib.list_local_devices()` returns, check if there is any device there with `device_type: "GPU"`. Have you rebooted after the update? You must make sure that Nvidia drivers are installed for your current kernel (`dkms status`) and are loaded (`lsmod | grep nvidia`). Do you get any log messages at all from TensorFlow when you try to create a session? Also, I have found that sometimes creating a first GPU session takes very long, then it works fine.

Comment: Also, you have _both_ `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` installed? You should have only one of them. And `tensorflow-gpu` currently supports CUDA 9.0, not 9.2 or 10.0 (unless Anaconda version is compiled differently).

Comment: I did reboot many times. `dkms status` has three warnings eg: `bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)` the other two look the same but with `4.15.0-43-generic` and `4.4.0-138-generic`. Gpu device is detected by `device_lib.list_local_devices()`

Comment: Yes I have both installed. `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` I will try downgrading CUDA and only having `tensorflow-gpu` thanks.

Comment: `conda install tensorflow-gpu` installs both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` packages but the `tensorflow` version is `1.12.0-gpu_py36he74679b_0` so I doubt that having both is a problem. I am still trying to downgrade to CUDA 9...